# Creating one new column out of two existing columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this table t1 with c1:old_email and c2:new_email

The goal: I want to create a new column/or query this table in a way so that I can use fields from c1 and c2 (basically merge the results from c1 and c2 into one column c3) and use it for a subquery in a where statement:

```
Select * from t2 where t2.email=(select c3 from t1)
```

```
name    |old_email  |new_email

:Johnny Go: JG@yahoo.com:   
:Bertie Post:   Bertie@hotmail.com: Bertie@gmail.com:
```

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you just want to match either of those emails or if you prefer one. If the idea is that you prefer `new_email` (i.e. will only use `old_email` if `new_email` doesn't exist), you might just want `COALESCE`. e.g. something like `SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.email = (SELECT COALESCE(new_email, old_email) FROM t1)

Comment: `merge the results from c1 and c2 into one column c3` Do you mean concatenate (possibly with a delimiter), as in c1 `a@b.c` and c2 `x@y.z` become c3 `a@b.c,z@y.z`?

Answer (score 0):

can't you join using both conditions?

```
select t2.* from
t2 join t1 on t2.email in (t1.old_email, t1.new_email)
```

or

```
select t2.*
from t1, t2
where t2.email = t1.old_email 
or t2.email = t1.new_email
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little ambiguous. I am going to infer you have a table like the one below, and you want to match either email address by joining a separate table of email addresses you have to identify matches.

| ID | NAME | OLD_EMAIL | NEW_EMAIL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | David Lin | david.lin@example.com | david@fakegoofmail.com |
| 2 | Christy Thomas | christy.thomas@example.com | christy@fakegoofmail.com |
| 3 | Erin Hill | erin.hill@example.com | erin@fakegoofmail.com |
| 4 | Noah Collins | noah.collins@example.com | noah@fakegoofmail.com |
| 5 | Andrew Salazar | andrew.salazar@example.com | andrew@fakegoofmail.com |

You are going to want to put both old_email and new_email in one column. We can do this with [unpivot](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/unpivot.html).

```
select 
    p.*
from t1
   unpivot(email for email_field in (old_email, new_email)) p;
```

The result would look like so.

| ID | NAME | EMAIL_FIELD | EMAIL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | David Lin | OLD_EMAIL | david.lin@example.com |
| 1 | David Lin | NEW_EMAIL | david@fakegoofmail.com |
| 2 | Christy Thomas | OLD_EMAIL | christy.thomas@example.com |
| 2 | Christy Thomas | NEW_EMAIL | christy@fakegoofmail.com |
| 3 | Erin Hill | OLD_EMAIL | erin.hill@example.com |
| 3 | Erin Hill | NEW_EMAIL | erin@fakegoofmail.com |
| 4 | Noah Collins | OLD_EMAIL | noah.collins@example.com |
| 4 | Noah Collins | NEW_EMAIL | noah@fakegoofmail.com |
| 5 | Andrew Salazar | OLD_EMAIL | andrew.salazar@example.com |
| 5 | Andrew Salazar | NEW_EMAIL | andrew@fakegoofmail.com |

Now you can join your secondary table of emails to perform email matching with a query like something below.

```
with t1_cte as (
select 
     p.*
 from t1
    unpivot(email for email_field in (old_email, new_email)) p order by 1
)
select t1.* from t1_cte t1
inner join seperate_table_of_emails t2 -- << your secondary table
    on t1.email = t2.email;
```